# Запись в json файл(С++/Cli)

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать запись в json файл значения из textBox(я поискал информацию, подключил библиотеку для json файлов, а именно nlohmann), но я не понимаю как отправлять в файл именно переменные, а не просто текст, а особенно я не понимаю как передавать туда значения типа String^.

```
{
    "Users": [
        {
           "Login" : "ivanvan",
            "Name" : "Иван",
            "Surname" : "Иванов",
        }
    ]
}
```

Вот такого вида должен быть файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это как выглядит окно формы

Comment: Писал уже много раз, повторю ещё раз: на языке C++/CLI не пишут полноценные приложения. Этот язык предназначен для одной цели: быть _клеем_ между управляемым и неуправляемым кодом. На нём пишут лишь оболочки (wrappers). Самое разумное, что вы сейчас можете сделать, это перейти либо на C#, либо на чистый C++.

Comment: На чистом с++ можно делать приложения с интерфейсом?

Comment: Можно. Но обычно C++ используют для написания высокопроизводительного кода. А GUI не подпадают под эту категорию. То есть на С++ пишут либу и используют её в приложении с интерфейсом, написанном на других языках, более высокоуровневых. Но это не обязательно, можно и всё на C++ сваять. / Теперь вам нужно выбрать графическую библиотеку. Не спрашивайте про это в комментариях! Задавайте новый вопрос. Однако, на stackoverflow не приветствуются вопросы с просьбами помочь в выборе библиотек. Так что вам прямая дорога на форумы.